# angular error Cannot find module 'rxjs/internal/Observable'

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic3, rxjs

estoy intentando hacer una aplicacion con ionic 3 que usa angular pero me lanza este error al utilizar la libreria @auth0/angular-jwt, al intentan reinstalar rxjs porque supongo que sera error de versiones, solo supongo... me lanza el error

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@5.2.10
`-- rxjs@5.5.0  invalid
```

he intentado

```
npm install @angular/common@5.2.10
```

pero sin exito no resuelvo el problema
el error justo es al agregar estas lineas

```
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
const helper = new JwtHelperService();
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Found that the 2.0.0 version of angular-jwt requires angular and rxjs in version 6+.

Ionic 3 currently supports only angular and rxjs in version 5+.

Using The version 1.2.0 of angular-jwt fixed the issue for me.

npm install @auth0/angular-jwt@1.2.0 --save-exact

Comment: Hi Romain. This site is [ES.SO] and the only accepted language is spanish. Please translate it or delete it. Thanks and regards

Answer (score -1):

Tuve el mismo problema.

Al parecer la versión 2.0.0 de `angular-jwt` requiere una versión de angular **6+.**
Ionic 3 actualmente soporta solamente angular y rxjs en la versión **5+**.

Usando la versión 1.2.0 de `angular-jwt` me funcionó.

`npm install @auth0/angular-jwt@1.2.0 --save-exact`.

A mi me funció perfectamente cambiando la versión 2.0.0 de `angular-jwt` del archivo package.json a la 1.2.0, borré la carpeta node_modules con

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Y volví a instalar las dependencias con `npm install` y funciona bien.